# Django Custom Field - Boolean -> CHAR YN

Tags: django

Due to a legacy system I'm trying to get Django boolean fields to save in the dB as a simple 'Y' or 'N' char field (VARCHAR not supported in said legacy system).

Using a django custom field I have it working but struggling to get Django admin to work with the field.

```
class BooleanYN(models.BooleanField):
    """ We need to save boolean variables as CHAR Y/N 

    """

    description = _("Boolean field stored as Y or N in the dB")

    def from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection):
        if value in ('Y', 'y'):
            return True
        if value in ('N', 'n'):
            return True
        raise ValidationError(_(f"Value in dB is not Y or N - {value}"))

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        if value is True:
            return 'Y'
        if value is False:
            return 'N'
        return value

    def db_type(self, connection):
        return char(1)
```

In Django admin, single record view + list view, the checkbox widget is always flagged as true even though 'N' is correctly saved in the dB and "to_python" is correctly being passed 'False' or 'True' as the value when its called by the modelform code depending on whether 'Y' or 'N' in the dB.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Any reason you don't define the DB field as a `CharField` with YN choices? For programming use you can define a model property that maps Y/N to True/False.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent so much time concentrating on the Django source code, I missed a stupid bug in my own code which I hid from myself with invalid logging!

Changed :

```
    def from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection):
        if value in ('Y', 'y'):
            return True
        if value in ('N', 'n'):
            return True
        raise ValidationError(_(f"Value in dB is not Y or N - {value}"))
```

to :

```
    def from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection):
        if value in ('Y', 'y'):
            return True
        if value in ('N', 'n'):
            return False
        raise ValidationError(_(f"Value in dB is not Y or N - {value}"))
```

Then no issues anymore.  Thanks for your reply nigel222